# Angular2 Unit Test Not Using Mock Service

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am testing a very simple component that shows/hides the login/out buttons.

For this I am mocking my `AuthService` service as that relies AngularFire2.

The problem I am having is that is appears my mock service (`Mock AuthService`) isn't being provided in place of the actual `AuthService`.

In the test `should show the Facebook login button`, `service.isAnonymous` is expected to be undefined. In the actual service, it is. But in the mock service is is `true`. This test should fail.

Also, notice I am trying to call the method `service.test(false);`; in the mock service this method exists and is `public`. But I receive the error:

> Property 'test' does not exist on type 'AuthService'.

This suggests that my mock service is not being provided.

You can see how I have tried two way to provide the mock service (one is commented out) in my test spec:

```
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import {
  async,
  inject,
  ComponentFixture,
  TestBed
} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { FacebookLoginComponent } from './facebook-login.component';
import { AuthService } from '../shared/auth.service';
import { MockAuthService } from '../shared/testing/auth.service';

describe('FacebookLoginComponent', () => {
  let authService: AuthService;
  let component: FacebookLoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FacebookLoginComponent>;
  let debugElement: DebugElement;
  let htmlElement: HTMLElement;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ FacebookLoginComponent ],
      // providers: [{ provide: AuthService, useValue: MockAuthService }]
    })
      .compileComponents();

    TestBed.overrideComponent(FacebookLoginComponent, {
      set: {
        providers: [{ provide: AuthService, useClass: MockAuthService }]
      }
    })
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FacebookLoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should show the Facebook login button', inject([ AuthService ], (service: AuthService) => {
    expect(service.isAnonymous).toBeUndefined();

    debugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button'));
    htmlElement = debugElement.nativeElement;

    service.test(false);

    expect(htmlElement.textContent).toBe('Facebook Login');
  }));

  it('should show the Logout button', () => {
    debugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button'));
    htmlElement = debugElement.nativeElement;

    expect(htmlElement.textContent).toBe('Logout');
  });
});
```

For completeness; here is my mock service, `MockAuthService`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MockAuthService {
  public authState: { isAnonymous: boolean, uid: string };

  constructor() {
    this.authState = { isAnonymous: true, uid: '0HjUd9owxPZ5kibvUCN6S2DgB4x1' };
  }

  // public get currentUser(): firebase.User {
  //   return this.authState ? this.authState : undefined;
  // }

  // public get currentUserObservable(): Observable<firebase.User> {
  //   return this.afAuth.authState;
  // }

  public get currentUid(): string {
    return this.authState ? this.authState.uid : undefined;
  }

  public get isAnonymous(): boolean {
    return this.authState ? this.authState.isAnonymous : false;
  }

  public get isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    return !!this.authState;
  }

  // public logout(): void {
  //   this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
  // }

  public test(isAnonymous: boolean) {
    this.authState.isAnonymous = isAnonymous;
  }
}
```

I am at a loss as to how to provide the mock instead.

## Update:

Based on answers and comments so far I have update my mock test spec. However, I am still having the same issue.

I get the error **Property 'test' does not exist on type 'AuthService'.**

This suggests it is still not substituting the mock for the actual `authService` service.

Furthermore, when I add:

```
public test(test: boolean): boolean {
  return test;
}
```

To the actual service the test fails; but not because of the error above, but because it should — the expectations of the test are not met.

This is my updated spec:

```
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import {
  async,
  inject,
  ComponentFixture,
  TestBed
} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { FacebookLoginComponent } from './facebook-login.component';
import { AuthService } from '../shared/auth.service';
import { MockAuthService } from '../shared/testing/auth.service';

describe('FacebookLoginComponent', () => {
  let authService: AuthService;
  let component: FacebookLoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FacebookLoginComponent>;
  let debugElement: DebugElement;
  let htmlElement: HTMLElement;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ FacebookLoginComponent ],
      providers: [{ provide: AuthService, useClass: MockAuthService }]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FacebookLoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should show the Facebook Login button', inject([ AuthService ], (service: AuthService) => {
    debugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button'));
    htmlElement = debugElement.nativeElement;

    expect(htmlElement.textContent).toBe('Facebook Login');
  }));

  it('should show the Logout button', inject([ AuthService ], (service: AuthService) => {
    expect(service.isAnonymous).toBe(true);

    debugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button'));
    htmlElement = debugElement.nativeElement;

    service.test(false);

    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(htmlElement.textContent).toBe('Logout');
  }));
});
```

Comment: It's a class, not a value; `useClass: MockAuthService`, or `useValue: new MockAuthService()`.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe, I've updated my test spec though I'm still having this problem. Please see my updated question.

Comment: What if you access `(service as MockAuthService).test`?

Comment: I then get the error `Type 'AuthService' cannot be converted to type 'MockAuthService'. Property 'authState' is private in type 'AuthService' but not in type 'MockAuthService'.` @jonrsharpe

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ FacebookLoginComponent ],
      // providers: [{ provide: AuthService, useValue: MockAuthService }]
    })
      .compileComponents();

    TestBed.overrideComponent(FacebookLoginComponent, {
      set: {
        providers: [{ provide: AuthService, useClass: MockAuthService }]
      }
    })
  }));
```

There are two problems.
You don't need to override component's providers because you can provide them when configuring the `TestBed`.

I assume that you've started overriding the component because the initial configuration didn't work. It didn't work because you've used `useValue` instead of `useClass`.

```
  // providers: [{ provide: AuthService, useValue: MockAuthService }]
```

This should do:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ FacebookLoginComponent ],
      providers: [{ provide: AuthService, useClass: MockAuthService }]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
```

**EDIT:**

When using `inject` function, you should use `MockAuthService` as a type. TypeScript should stop complaining.

```
inject([ AuthService ], (service: MockAuthService) => { /* ... */ });
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, though unfortunately this still seems to be using the original (not the mock) service, please see my updated question.

Answer (score 3):

So, I was struggling and losing my mind over this same issue. I had 2 services in my component I needed to mock for testing. One (let's call it `MyService`) was successfully using a mock, and the other (let's call `MyOtherService`) wouldn't use the mock but the actual service.

Eventually I figured it out (kinda).
So this is the class/component I was testing:

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-my-component",
  templateUrl: "./my-component.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./my-component.component.scss"],
  providers: [MyOtherService]
})
export class MyComponentComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
 ...private logic...

  constructor(
    private myService: MyService,
    private myOtherService: MyOtherService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {}

..component logic...
```

See something that `MyOtherService` is doing that `MyService` isn't?.....
It's in the providers in the `@Component`!

Turns out I didn't really need that service there when I had it in my constructor, so I removed it and the test started using the mock instead of the actual service.

So, I would check if you're adding services in constructor or in the providers in the `@Component`.

Now, I think there must be a way to still mock services that are declared in the providers in the `@Component`, but I wasn't able to figure that out and it was easier to remove it since my constructor was getting the service anyway.

I know your question is very old but I hope this helps!

Comment: Your post was very useful. In exchange I can point you to another answer which address just your question about how mock a provider from the @Component. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62589594/test-component-with-a-providers