# Angular Unit Test - How to get reference to a component scoped provider?

Tags: angular, unit-testing

Given that I have a component that is registering a provider such as:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: '<div></div>',
  providers: [MyService]
})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

  doSomething() {
    this.myService.doThis();
  }
}
```

How should I get a reference to this service/provider in a unit test?

Until now I have 'cheated' and accessed the private component variable using the object map

```
service = component['myService'] as MyService;
```

However, I imagine that Angular or the TestBed should provide a more robust way to get this instance?  Something similar to TestBed.inject(MyService), but working with component scoped providers.

I have created a working [stackblitz example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gdtquv?file=src/app/my-tests.spec.ts)

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62589594/test-component-with-a-providers

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez. Yes thank you, this is what  looking for.