# Mocked function returns wrong value

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to mock a service that is used in my component.

This is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SimpleService } from './simple-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  providers: [SimpleService],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public bar = false;
  
  constructor(private simpleService: SimpleService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.bar = this.simpleService.foo();
  }
}
```

This is my service:

```
export class SimpleService {
    foo(): boolean {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And this is my jasmine test:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { SimpleService } from './simple-service';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let mockSimpleService : jasmine.SpyObj<SimpleService>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    mockSimpleService = jasmine.createSpyObj<SimpleService>('SimpleService', ['foo']);
    mockSimpleService.foo.and.returnValue(false)
    
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      providers: [{ provide: SimpleService, useValue: mockSimpleService }]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    mockSimpleService.foo.and.returnValue(false)
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('foobar', () => {
    expect(component.bar).toBe(true);
  });

  it('foobar mock', () => {
    mockSimpleService.foo.and.returnValue(false)
    expect(component.bar).toBe(false);
  });
});
```

As you can see I tried mocking the `foo` method at different locations, however the 'foobar' test case is succeeding while the 'foobar mock' test case is failing.

How can I mock the `foo` method of my service?

Comment: What I usually do is mocking after the module has been created and works just fine.

`await compileComponents(); let s = TestBed.inject(Service); jasmine.spyOn(s, 'fn').and.returnValue(false)`

Comment: You've made it more complicated to use a test double by having the service be a _component-level_ provider; is that really necessary? Either have the service at a module/root level, or see https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#override-component-providers.

Comment: @Some random IT boy: I removed all references to my mock and used your suggestion like this: `await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      providers: [{ provide: SimpleService }]
    }).compileComponents();
    const s : SimpleService = TestBed.inject(SimpleService);
    spyOn(s, 'foo').and.returnValue(false);`, however it still doen't work.

Comment: I see that you're providing the service from your @Component which is incorrect. Services are provided from Modules (in your case I am guessing it should be the AppModule), do also mark `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})` your service

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Test component with a providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62589594/test-component-with-a-providers)

Comment: Another thing that seems a little bit odd is that the component is created and then the service mocked. So the instance of the component holds a reference to a non-mocked service; I believe

Comment: @jonrsharpe @Some random IT boy: I added `@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})` to my service, however the result is still the same.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? The component-level injection is a separate instance. If that's not the behaviour you want, don't provide it at that level.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Sorry, I thought your comment about my service not being injectable at root level was trying to solve my problem.

Comment: @SomerandomITboy: Creating the service mock right before the component creation, like this: `mockSimpleService = jasmine.createSpyObj<SimpleService>('SimpleService', ['foo']);
    mockSimpleService.foo.and.returnValue(false)
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);` did not help, unfortunately.

Comment: Only call `fixture.detectChanges();` right before expecting `bar` property.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jonrsharpe and @hoangdv, I found the solution:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { SimpleService } from './simple-service';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [App Component],
      providers: [{ provide: SimpleService, useClass: SimpleService }]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('foobar', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.bar).toBe(true);
  });

  it('foobar mock', () => {
    const sps = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(SimpleService);
    spyOn(sps, 'foo').and.returnValue(false);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.bar).toBe(false);
  });
});
```

Now both `foobar` and `foobar mock` test cases succeed.